# How to inject IEnumerable using Microsoft Unity IOC container

Tags: inversion-of-control, unity-container

I have a Service that need inject more than one provider, see below for example. How to use Unity to implement this feature?

```
public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public MyService(IEnumerable<Provider> Providers);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but maybe this will help someone else that stumbles upon this.

As long as you register the implementations with a specific name, this is possible to easily inject. You will then get all registered implementations.

```
public class MyService: IMyService
{
    public MyService(IProvider[] providers)
    {
       // Do something with the providers
    }
}
```

Just make sure to inject them as an array. Unity will understand this. And when you register them you can register them as such:

```
container.RegisterType<IProvider, FooProvider>("Foo");
container.RegisterType<IProvider, BarProvider>("Bar");
```

Answer (score -3):

One way is to inject the UnityContainer itself, and then resolve all the Providers you need:

```
public class MyService : IMyService 
{
    public class MyService(IUnityContainer iocContainer)
    {
        var providers = iocContainer.ResolveAll<IProvider>();
    }
}
```

The only thing you will need to do is register the UnityContainer with itself somewhere on setup:

```
unityContainer.Register<IUnityContainer>(unityContainer, new ContainerControllerLifetimeManager());
```

Comment: Thank you . I know this way, but I don't like it , since I need to write one more code:)

Comment: Please don't share the container object with external classes. Only one class should know the ioc container!
@TonyWoo: Use container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<Provider>, Provider[]>();

Comment: in some situations you can't go around it. And I would suggest posting that comment as an answer.